# Changing volume of alarm on Nokia Lumia 800

Tags: 7.8, volume, nokia-lumia-800, alarms

I have a Nokia Lumia 800 with Windows Phone 7.8 on it and I am unable to control the volume of the alarms for the alarm clock on the phone.  I used to have an LG Optimus with Windows Phone 7 on it and I was able to adjust the volume, so I think it might have something to do with the phone rather than the OS, but I'm not sure.  Does anyone know if it's an issue with the Nokia Lumia 800 specifically, and if there is a way to fix it so that I can adjust the alarm volume?

Answer (score 2):

From [Windows Phone Help](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/set-alarms-on-my-phone):

> Alarm volume is **separate from the overall phone volume** and **can't be**
>   **changed**. As long as your phone is on, your alarms will still ring out
>   nice and loud even if you turn down or silence the phone volume.

The above applies to any Windows Phone out there. I used to have an LG Optimus too and I can't remember being allowed to set the volume for built-in alarms.